# How to create a React Native iOS module that depends on another xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm creating the RN module for text input mask – https://github.com/ivanzotov/react-native-text-input-mask, and the iOS part depends on https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-ios project.

After installing my module with `npm i --save react-native-text-input-mask` and link with `react-native link` everything is ok in simulator but when I try to install it on a real device I have to link the InputMask from Products to Embedded Binaries in the XCode.

What is the right way to create a RN module so dependency linked automatically?